# Parse string inside a column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing, split

I'm trying to parse out the "select investors" column into individual columns (ex. investor1, investor2, investor3) in this dataset: https://www.cbinsights.com/research-unicorn-companies

I tried this code:

```
df_worldunicorns[['tier1','tier2','tier3']] = df_worldunicorns['Select Investors'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

but get the following error:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Please help

Comment: Some cells contain more than 3 values. `df['Select Investors'].str.split(',', expand=True).shape # (1230, 4)`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by [*@Psidom*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77167796/parse-string-inside-a-column-pandas#comment136039085_77167796), at least one row, of the inverstors, doesn't hold two commas (`,`).

You can try this instead :

```
df_worldunicorns = pd.read_html(
    "https://www.cbinsights.com/research-unicorn-companies",
    storage_options={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"})[0]

tiers = ( # or use `.pop` to exclude the original column
    df_worldunicorns["Select Investors"].str.split(",\s*", expand=True)
        .rename(lambda c: f"tier_{c+1}", axis=1)
        )

df_worldunicorns = df_worldunicorns.join(tiers)
```

And if you really want three columns, add `n=2` to [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) :

```
df_worldunicorns[['tier1', 'tier2', 'tier3']] = (
    df["Select Investors"].str.split(",\s*", n=2, expand=True) # <-- added here
)
```

Output :

```
print(df_worldunicorns) # without `n=2`

                  Company Valuation ($B) Date Joined  ...                     tier_2                    tier_3          tier_4
0               ByteDance           $225    4/7/2017  ...       SIG Asia Investments                Sina Weibo  SoftBank Group
1                  SpaceX           $137   12/1/2012  ...    Draper Fisher Jurvetson       Rothenberg Ventures            None
2                   SHEIN            $66    7/3/2018  ...      Sequoia Capital China  Shunwei Capital Partners            None
3                  Stripe            $50   1/23/2014  ...           LowercaseCapital                  capitalG            None
4              Databricks            $43    2/5/2019  ...  New Enterprise Associates          Battery Ventures            None
...                   ...            ...         ...  ...                        ...                       ...             ...
1225          LeadSquared             $1   6/21/2022  ...          Stakeboat Capital        WestBridge Capital            None
1226            FourKites             $1   6/21/2022  ...      Bain Capital Ventures          Hyde Park Angels            None
1227          VulcanForms             $1    7/5/2022  ...        D1 Capital Partners         Industry Ventures            None
1228          SingleStore             $1   7/12/2022  ...                      Accel           Data Collective            None
1229  Unstoppable Domains             $1   7/27/2022  ...          Draper Associates                  Gaingels            None

[1230 rows x 11 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
temp_df = df_worldunicorns['Select Investors'].str.split(', ', expand=True) #split to a new dataframe

temp_df.columns = ["tier" + str(i) for i in temp_df.columns] # rename columns

df_worldunicorns = pd.concat([df_worldunicorns,temp_df],axis=1) #concat main df and temp_df
```